# Find highest common sibling branch in file structure

Tags: algorithm

I got an array with file structure and I need to find highest relationships. I have a script that return tree structures and I need to remove the duplicates.

This 'path' will be split by '/'.

```
var array = [
        '2/7',
        '2/6',
        '2/8/4/6',
        '1/3',
        '1/4',
        '1',
        '1/5/1/4',
        '2',
        '3/test'
    ]
```

This should output:

```
var return = [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3/test'
    ]
```

How would I perform this?

I'm scanning directories for deleted directories. Let's say I'm deleting "2", but my monitoring script notices that entire branch is gone: 2, 2/7, 2/6, 2/8/4/6 and it reports it, instead of deleting dirs as they come, I'm storing structure to be deleted in array. I need to return array without duplicates delete same directories on remote machine

Comment: why should it return your output? The logic is not clear. How is 2 a duplicate of 2/8/4/6?

Comment: Salvador Dali, I'm scanning directories for deleted directories. Let's say I'm deleting "2", but my monitoring script notices that entire branch is gone: 2, 2/7, 2/6, 2/8/4/6 and it reports it, instead of deleting dirs as they come, I'm storing structure to be deleted in array. I need to return array without duplicates delete same directories on remote machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is how you can achieve this. Create a imaginary root. Mark it as white.

Now go through each of your elements and populate it from the root. For example `'2/8/4/6'` will create a path `root -> 2 -> 8 -> 4 -> 6`. Each vertex is colored as white and the last one colored as black.

If you will do this, you will get the tree like this:

[image]
Now do [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) from root will you will encounter the black vertex. Your paths will be:

```
root -> 2
root -> 1
root -> 3 -> test
```

Ignore the root and you get what you want.

Comment: Nicely explained with the diagram.

Comment: Took me a while to digest this, but I think I got enough idea to start coding this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trie data structure to find unique prefixes. Now a trie uses a lot of memory, so you may have to adapt it.

1. Start with a empty trie.
2. Traverse trie for each path in your input array.

   - Start from root, and add the first character of your path as a new child of root if it is not there. Otherwise just move to the child.
   - Repeat the procedure till character `/`
   - After this there are two cases possible

     1. The branch of the trie that was being traversed, has reached its end. The path has also reached its end, or it has some more characters left. Either way you can drop the remaining path, and process the next path in input.
     2. The path has reached its end, but the trie's branch has children nodes. In this case you can truncate all the children of current trie's branch.

I have not elaborated on handling `/` delimiter. You will have to account for it carefully.